# Can google mini search a liferay portal that uses CAS authentication?

Tags: search, liferay, tridion

We are setting up a portal based on Liferay at the same time we are moving our insitution's intranet onto Tridion CMS.

Tridion is using google mini as its search tool, while Liferay is using lucene.

What we want is a single search that indexes both systems.

The big issue for us is that Liferay is using CAS for authentication and we are not sure how to get google mini authenticated into liferay.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  I am going to create a service-api-admin account in liferay and add an additional authentication *AutoLogin* via the auto.login.hooks property (in portal-ext.properties).  That authenticator will use the liferay database password value to verify the service-api-admin account without going through CAS so you will be able to supply authentication with your REST calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can set LDAP for Liferay and Google mini can LDAP too.